# on-key in racket

Tags: scheme, racket

```
(require 2htdp/image)
(require 2htdp/universe)

(define (render t)
  (text (number->string t) 10 "red"))

(define (ball-image t)
  (place-image (circle 10 "solid" "red")
              150
              150

               (empty-scene 300 300)))



(define (change w a-key)
  (cond
    [(key=? a-key "left")  (ball-image w)]
    [(key=? a-key "right") (ball-image w )]
    [(= (string-length a-key) 1) w] 
    [(key=? a-key "up")    (ball-image w )]
    [(key=? a-key "down")  (ball-image w )]
    [else w]))



(big-bang 100
          (on-tick sub1 )
          (to-draw ball-image)
          (on-key change))
```

I am trying to get the red ball I have placed in the middle to  move up, down, left, or right. When I press any of the arrow keys, it says it expects a number but given an image. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are your contracts?  Where are the purpose statements for your functions?  It's not clear what the purpose of each function _is_; rather than force folks to guess, write it out.

Comment: Do you have any test cases for `change`?

Comment: sub1 is actually a numerical procedure, so it takes number. In the (on-tick ...) place should be a function, which transforms so called WorldState each tick.

Comment: @Necto: sub1 would be a perfectly good function from worlds to worlds, if the OP had described what the world state _is_.  Without even that amount of information, we can't say anything.  That's why I'm trying to force the OP to express something other than the code: they haven't said at all what the types are supposed to be, and pretty much ignored the fundamental Design Recipe steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to understand how the world is processed in this main circle:

- The system takes the first argument of big-bang - 100, and remembers it as a *WorldState*.
- Then it passes it to a on-tick (**sub1**) function, provided it exists on each tick.
- When the key is pressed, it calls on-key (**change**) and passes the *woldState* there, as a w argument.
- There you draw some pictures and return it in case of an arrow key is pressed. So when an arrow is pressed, it returns the result of **ball-image** = result of **place-image** - *image*
- The system remembers it as a current *worldState*,
  and with the next tick, it passes the new value to the old procedure: **sub1**.
- Since the value is now an *image*, **sub1** rejects it.

--

If you want to move a ball in two directions, you have to store at least two coordinates (x . y). So let now the *WorldState* be the pair of two numbers. We don't need a on-tick function, since nothing changes on its own. Also we don't need to draw the ball in the keyboard processor, so let's simple change the corresponding value in the pair (*worldState*), and draw it only during the call (**ball-image**) which puts the ball into the new place (remember, x = (car t), y = (cdr t), and (x . y) = (cons x y)):

```
(require 2htdp/image)
(require 2htdp/universe)

(define (ball-image t) ;<-- the t-parameter is our WorldState
  (place-image (circle 10 "solid" "red")
               (car t) ;<-- here now x variable coordinate
               (cdr t) ;<-- here now y variable, instead of 150
               (empty-scene 300 300)))



(define (change w a-key)
  (cond ;w - is the previous worldState, V here we change it
    [(key=? a-key "left")  (cons (sub1 (car w)) (cdr w))];and 
    [(key=? a-key "right") (cons (add1 (car w)) (cdr w))];return 
    [(= (string-length a-key) 1) w] ;<-- this line is excess
    [(key=? a-key "up")    (cons (car w) (sub1 (cdr w)))]
    [(key=? a-key "down")  (cons (car w) (add1 (cdr w)))]
    [else w])) ;<-- If the key of no interest, just
                    return the previous WorldState

(big-bang '(150 . 150) ;<-- initial state
          (to-draw ball-image) ;<-- redraws the world
          (on-key change)) ;<-- process the event of key press
```